# Select elements in list by name

Tags: r, regex, list, subset

I am trying to select all of the elements in a list that have a name that is like a string.

```
x <- list('not_bob' = list(1,2,3), 'bob' = list(1,4,5), 'Al' = '1', 'Ally' = '3')

e <- x[names(x) %in% c('bob', '%Al%')]
```

Desired output:

`e` contains `bob`, `Al` and `Ally`.

Comment: If you are trying to use regular expressions or globbing, you'll need `grep` or `grepl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not comfortable with regular expressions (it's understandable!), then you can continue with "normal wildcarding". To use SQL patterns as you've shown will take a little translation, so I suggest you make the ever-so-slight shift to wildcarding or globbing.

For instance, your `"%Al%"` in SQL is equivalent to:

- wildcard: `"*Al*"`
- regex: `glob2rx("*Al*")` --> `"^.*Al"` (nothing is required post-`Al` since the regex is somewhat permissive lacking limits ... compare with `glob2rx("*Al")` to see the difference)

Try this:

```
ptns <- c("bob", "*Al*")
x[ grepl(paste(glob2rx(ptns), collapse="|"), names(x)) ]
# $bob
# $bob[[1]]
# [1] 1
# $bob[[2]]
# [1] 4
# $bob[[3]]
# [1] 5
# $Al
# [1] "1"
# $Ally
# [1] "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **regular expressions**. In R this can be done with a `grepl` function:

```
e <- x[grepl("^bob$|^Al.*$", names(x))]
```

`|` separates different strings, `^` denotes the start of the string, `$` - the end of the string and `.*` means any number of any symbols. You might have to study regular expressions more if your needs are more complex.